# Bycrpt cannot compare and always sends null values

Tags: mysql, node.js

i m using Bycrpty library for security. so i read bycrpt Official document.

i sent postman in signup routes. it work or not

it was success full! like that.

[image]

so i have to compare the passwords When logging in,
but compare is always failed. it's my code..

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// const { Op } = require("sequelize");
const { user } = require("../../models");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10) ; 


  signUpController: async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password} = req.body;
    
    if( !(username && email && password) ){
      res.status(405).send({
        "message" : "invalid request"
      });
    }
    else{
      const userInfo = await user.findOne({
        where: {
              email: email,
              username : username
        }
      });

      if(userInfo === null){
          const newUser = await user.create({ 
            username: username, 
            email : email, 
            password:  bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt), 
          });

          let response = {  
            username: newUser.username,
            email: newUser.email,
            username: newUser.username,
            password : newUser.password
          }
       
        res.status(201).json( response );
      }
      else{
          res.status(409).send({
              "message" : "email already exist"
          });
        }
    }
  },

  login : async(req,res)=>{
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const userInfo = await user.findOne({
      where: {
            email: email,
            password : password
      }
    });
    // console.log("req: ", req)
    if(!userInfo) {
      await res.status(400).send({data : null, message : 'not authorized'})
    }
      else {
          const data = {...userInfo.dataValues}
          console.log('password:', checkMail.password)
          bcrypt.compareSync(password, userInfo.password) ;  

          delete data.password

          const accessToken = jwt.sign(data, process.env.ACCESS_SECRET, {expiresIn : '3h'}) // create jwt 
          const refreshToken = jwt.sign(data, process.env.REFRESH_SECRET, {expiresIn : '1h'}) //  save in cookie .
       
        res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken) 
        res.status(200).send({data:{"accessToken": accessToken}, message:'ok'})
    }
  }
```

What should I do to be successful? I need advice and tips.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly confused as your using async/await for some things like the database library however not for bcrypt which also has promises and instead you're using their `sync` versions. As a first advice I wouldn't use the `sync` versions of the code as they block the eventLoop.

There is another problem with your logic - which is highlighted below.

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// const { Op } = require("sequelize");
const { user } = require("../../models");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10) ; 


  signUpController: async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password} = req.body;
    
    if( !(username && email && password) ){
      res.status(405).send({
        "message" : "invalid request"
      });
    }
    else{

      const userInfo = await user.findOne({
        where: {
              email: email,
              username : username
        }
      });
      // using email/username as unique fields to find a user and check if they already have an account
      if(userInfo === null){
          const newUser = await user.create({ 
            username: username, 
            email : email, 
            password:  bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt),
            // saving the hashed password rather than the plaintext password
          });

          let response = {  
            username: newUser.username,
            email: newUser.email,
            username: newUser.username,
            password : newUser.password
          }
          // do not under any circumstance send the password back to the user.
       
        res.status(201).json( response );
      }
      else{
          res.status(409).send({
              "message" : "email already exist"
          });
        }
    }
  },

  login : async(req,res)=>{
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // you're trying to find a user that exists based on their email and plaintext password, but the password you've saved is the HASHED version not the plaintext version so this result will always be empty... No such user exists
    const userInfo = await user.findOne({
      where: {
            email: email,
            password : password
      }
    });
    // console.log("req: ", req)
    if(!userInfo) {
      // hence this error is present ALL THE TIME
      await res.status(400).send({data : null, message : 'not authorized'})
    }
      else {
          const data = {...userInfo.dataValues}
          console.log('password:', checkMail.password)
          bcrypt.compareSync(password, userInfo.password) ;  
          // you wouldn't need this step as you've found the user based on the password
          delete data.password

          const accessToken = jwt.sign(data, process.env.ACCESS_SECRET, {expiresIn : '3h'}) // create jwt 
          const refreshToken = jwt.sign(data, process.env.REFRESH_SECRET, {expiresIn : '1h'}) //  save in cookie .
       
        res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken) 
        res.status(200).send({data:{"accessToken": accessToken}, message:'ok'})
    }
  }
```

This seems to me rather than misunderstanding how password hashing works you don't understand the data in your database.

I'd suggest to get a visual database explorer for whatever database you're trying to use. There are many free and opensource ones out there!

Comment: Ohh i see .. are you can tell me some visual database explorer? :)
i wanna know more about that. just looking for in google?

Comment: Which database are you using - Postgres MySQL - MongoDB ?

Comment: It seems you've tagged your question with MySQL so i'm guessing MySQL: https://tableplus.com/ this is one of my favourites and the free version is very usable - just you can only have 3 tabs open. But this should help!

Comment: it's MySQL :)  I m using